# MKMapView userLocation return coordinates 0.0;0.0 on app's first launch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, mkmapview, core-location

I'm currently developing an app that have use an MKMapView control. It is suppose to show the user's location via the blue dot (like the Maps application), but when the app is first installed on the device and then launched, you have the prompt asking the user for the authorization, but once accepted, the user's location is not showed on the map, and the coordinates returned are 0.0 ; 0.0.

Then, I turn off the app, remove it from multitasking and start it again, and the position is showed correctly and correct coordinates are returned.

I also use CoreLocation in order to be able to calculate the distance between two points and get the heading, and I set it up with a custom message for the prompt, which is show one out of two fresh installs of the app (I wonder why), I do not really care about that last problem, but it might help to know that detail.

What should I do to be able to get that blue do to show on the app's first launch?

Sincerely,

Max

Comment: It can take time to update the users location. It uses core location to update the users current location. This would probably call -[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation] or some similar method to update the current location. These method return immediately and sets call back such that when the location is found, it gets called.  To stop the blue set some selector to call after certain delay.

Comment: Well, That's what I thought too, except I left it for an hour, without any change, I tried on a 3GS on iOS 6 same problem, but works fine on the simulator.

Comment: Check to see if the location update for the application is disabled in settings. Otherwise, it should be very simple, needs no coding at all. Simply dragging map view in storyboard and checking the shows user location option should be able to do it.

Comment: Well now I realized. It seems it is some kind of bug. I guess you will have to set delegate to the map and when the didUpdateLocation delegate is received add annotation yourself. Or else, use core location to update location and then add annotation.

Comment: Well, seems like the only way too, CoreLocation is returning me good data, so I'll try to implement it as a replacement of the MKMapCiew ShowUserLocation for the first launch only, my only concern is to see what will happen regarding the heading since I use the method "MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this happens sometimes with iPhone (not in simulator), I also experienced the same issue, and it crashes the app if you try to zoom the map to the given location. You may like to use following code to avoid this case. This will discard invalid GPS updates and eventually you will start getting valid data

```
if (mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude <= -180.0f
    || mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude >= 180.0f
    || mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude <= -180.0f
    || mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude >= 180.0f
    || (mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude == 0.0f 
    && mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude == 0.0f) ) {

    return; // or something else you may like to do
} 

// rest of the code
```